# Bind Json to the DropDownList in MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dropdown

my json string in developer tool network tab is:

```
[{\"id\":\"20\",\"name\":\"System Team\"}]
```

My Controller code is

```
public class Teams
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> names { get; set; }

    public string[] team { get; set; }
}
public ActionResult Teams()
{  
    //Covert JSON to .net object using Deserialize method

    var jsonString ="[{\"id\":\"20\",\"name\":\"System Team\"}]";
    JavaScriptSerializer javaScriptSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    List<Teams> listTeams = (List<Teams>)javaScriptSerializer.Deserialize(jsonString,typeof(List<Teams>));

    foreach (Teams teams in listTeams)
    {
        Response.Write("" + teams.name + "<br/>");
    }
}
```

My View Code is :

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Teams";  
}   
@Html.DropDownList("names",null,"--Select Teams--")
```

How Can I bind the json data which is **name:system team** to the dropdownlist?
I want the "system team" coming as a value in the dropdownlist. I am using MVC 4 Framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like a [SelectList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist(v=vs.118).aspx)

In your controller:

```
public ActionResult Teams()
{  
    //Covert JSON to .net object using Deserialize method
    var jsonString ="[{\"id\":\"20\",\"name\":\"System Team\"}]";
    JavaScriptSerializer javaScriptSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    List<Teams> listTeams = (List<Teams>)javaScriptSerializer.Deserialize(jsonString,typeof(List<Teams>));

    var teamList = new List<SelectListItem>();
    foreach (Teams teams in listTeams)
    {
        var listItem = new SelectListItem{ Value = teams.id, Text = teams.name };
        teamList.Add(listItem);
    }

    ViewData["teamList"] = teamList;
```

}

In your view:

```
@Html.DropDownList("names", new SelectList((List<SelectListItem>)ViewData["teamList"], "Value", "Text"), "--Select Teams--")
```